# How to start a download upon this StoreKit message?

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase, storekit

On a fresh app install, when I try to re-purchase an item to re-download it my app sends a purchase request to Store Kit.

Then I get `SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing`, and Store Kit prompts the user to confirm the purchase.

Then Store Kit responds with this message on iOS 7: "**You've already purchased this in-App Purchase but it hasn't been downloaded.**".

Then, Store Kit fails with `SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed` and error is

Previously StoreKit would just let the user re-download the content instead. But now it fails with error code 2 "**Cannot connect to iTunes Store**". If I do a complete restore then Store Kit allows to download content, but this particular item still fails. Also note the test device has WiFi and stable internet connection and StoreKit was able to resolve that the item is purchased. So this error is bogus.

Is this a new change in iOS 7? How can I let the user re-download a single item without forcing to re-download all?

According to this [Technical Note](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2259/_index.html), the problem occurs if there is a purchase transaction that was not finished. I tripple-checked that I call finish transaction and it happens after I get the error. So the transaction does get closed.

Comment: I saw this happen when I had to update my credit card during an in app purchase. I think if you do this while not in your app you still get the store kit dialogs but your app doesn't get notified of the finished transaction. Smells like a bug in iOS 7. My guess is this specific scenario got missed in the QA process.

Comment: I was in a similar situation; resolved by restarting my iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

You have some unfinished transactions in the payment queue. To finish them check the  `paymentQueue.transactions` array right after adding your observer with `addTransactionObserver:` method. If it contains some transactions handle them the way you do in your `paymentQueue:updatedTransactions:` method.
If you don't, `paymentQueue:updatedTransactions:` is not called for them because they were already in the queue when you have registered the observer.

By the way, make sure you call `finishTransaction:` for all of your transactions even if they have failed. Otherwise they will stay in the payment queue and cause this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here.. we launched a new update for our app after iOS 7 release. We have many users now complaining  that they are either unable to restore previous purchases. Other users are complaining that their purchase is successful, however the IAP package does not unlock with no error message.. we are a bit baffled here.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem ! After checking for hours! I just restarted the I pad (iOS7), and now again its working.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by signing out the test account from the App Store via Settings app -> App Store -> Sign Out. Then I removed the test account from iTunes Connect, then I rebooted the device.

Answer (score -1):

I was in a similar situation; resolved by restarting my iPhone.  Specifically, I had non-consumable purchase hosted on Apple's Server.  Installed app to iphone5, made purchase.  Deleted App, reinstalled in another build, and upon restore, ITunesStore server didn't respond with my hosted-contact productIdentifier. Purchasing the item again produces "already purchased" error, without an option to download. I found this site, http://support.nimblebit.com/customer/portal/articles/672080-problem-making-in-app-purchase-ios-os-x; restarted my device, and restore now recognizes the previous purchase.